# How does the stalled() function work in Pybricks-MicroPython

Tags: micropython, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3, pybricks-micropython

MicroPython 2.0 beta 5

Trying to understand how the `stalled()` function on the motor works. I run a motor at dc of 100, and hold the wheel so that it cannot move.

But the `stalled` function doesn't fire, indeed whatever I do I don't seem able to get it to return True?

I tried with less power, but still not able to get anything out of this function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks import ev3brick as brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import Motor
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Stop

left_motor = Motor(Port.B) 

speed = 800

# option 1
left_motor.dc(100)

# option 2
#left_motor.run_until_stalled(speed, Stop.HOLD, 100)

while True:
    if left_motor.stalled():
        print("stalled")
```

If I use option 1: the motor runs, I hold it until it stops, nothing reported. I let go and off it goes again.

If I use option 2: the motor runs, I hold it, it stops. But at no point do I see a report saying it stalled.

Comment: What platform are you running MicroPython on, and can you include your MicroPython code in the question please? `stalled` isn't part of base MicroPython so you must be getting this function from some additional library.

Comment: I am running it on the LEGO mindstorms ev3dev.org build with the MicroPython I downloaded from the LEGO website and subsequently updated with apt-get commands. So it is pybricks library I think. I edited the subject line to make it more specific.

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: @nekomatic I edited the question and included some code.

Comment: OK, I've found [the docs for the library](https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/python-for-ev3) you seem to be using and if you've read what it says there about `stalled()` and `run_until_stalled()` then I've no further ideas. Have you tried the [ev3dev2](https://python-ev3dev.readthedocs.io/en/ev3dev-stretch/index.html) library instead? I'm deleting my answer as it clearly wasn't correct.

Comment: I did try using Python3, but switched too microPython since it is significantly faster, the chosen path of the LEGO company. Which gives me another idea, I ask LEGO support the question. Thanks @nekomatic.

Answer (score 1):

A motor is stalled when it can't reach its target speed or angle, despite applying the maximum duty cycle.

Your example can be adapted like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks.ev3devices import Motor
from pybricks.parameters import Port
from pybricks.tools import wait

# Initialize the motor
left_motor = Motor(Port.B)

# Start running the motor at 500 deg/s
left_motor.run(500)

# Do nothing until we are stalled
while not left_motor.stalled():
    wait(10)

# Stop the motor
left_motor.stop()
```

This example is equivalent to the one-liner `left_motor.run_until_stalled(500)`. The manual approach can be useful if you want to extend it to multiple motors.

The `dc()` method in the question does not set a target speed or angle; it sets the duty cycle directly, so there is no stall information.

Note: the `left_motor.stalled()` method is instead accessible through `left_motor.control.stalled()` as of Pybricks version Pybricks 2.0. It is in public beta only as of March 2020, so I'm not sure the version reported in the original post in August 2019 is correct.